# Apex: Looping the wrapper records

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I'm trying to loop the list of records and add to the `selectedAccounts` only if the `isSelected == true`

If you look at the data and you will find the record of `Jolly` is selected == true. but in my case its never adding to to the selectedAccount.

```
for(accountwrapper  accwrapper : accountList)
{
  if(accwrapper.isSelected == true)
  {
    selectedAccounts.add(accwrapper.oAccount);
  } 
}
```

Here is my `accountList` data spitting:

```
AccountWrapper:
[contactset=(
    ContactWrapper:[isSelected=false, oContact=Contact:{AccountId=0011a000004L8AdAAK, Id=0031a000007hwc2AAA, Name=John}],       
    ContactWrapper:[isSelected=true, oContact=Contact:{AccountId=0011a000004L8AdAAK, Id=0031a000007jjANAAY, Name=Jolly}], 
    ContactWrapper:[isSelected=false, oContact=Contact:{AccountId=0011a000004L8AdAAK, Id=0031a000007jjAWAAY, Name=Harry, Email=, Phone=}]), 
    isSelected=false,   
    oAccount=Account:{Id=0011a000004L8AdAAK, Name=BMW, BillingCountry=USA, CreatedById=0051a000000QWaBAAW}
]
```

Here is my code trying to add to the `selectedAccounts` only if the `isSelected == true`

```
    public class AccountWrapper
    {
        public account oAccount{get;set;}
        public boolean isSelected{get;set;}
        public List<ContactWrapper> contactset{get;set;}

        public AccountWrapper(account a, boolean b, List<ContactWrapper> c)
        {
            oAccount=a;
            isSelected=b;
            contactset =c;            
        }
    }  

    public class ContactWrapper
    {
        public Contact oContact { get; set; }
        public boolean isSelected { get; set; }

        public ContactWrapper(Contact a)
        {
            oContact=a;
            isSelected=false;                       
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try putting a system.debug() just before your if condition to see if the isSelected is indeed getting set as true when you are creating your list.

Comment: You're confusing your contacts for your accounts. The contact wrapper is selected, but the account wrapper is *not*. There's nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand but if you look at the data it is setting isSelected = true and what you see is that i'm trying to read the data from `accountlist`

Comment: @sfdcfox: yes i think so too so should i be using contactwrapper instead of accountwrapper?, i'm confused too :)

Comment: @AbuHamzah You have Accounts that contain lists of Contacts. Both have a selection Boolean value. Jolly is a Contact on the Account. The Account is *not* selected, and the Contact is. If you want to find your Contacts that are selected, you'll want to loop through each Account wrapper, then through each Contact wrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Accounts that contain lists of Contacts. Both have a selection Boolean value. Jolly is a Contact on the Account. The Account is *not* selected, and the Contact is. If you want to find your Contacts that are selected, you'll want to loop through each Account wrapper, then through each Contact wrapper.